# How to turn php time function into javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm not that good at javascript (yet), so I need some help, with an alternative version of this php script (In javascript)

```
function until($format = ""){
    $now = strtotime("now");
    $nextTuesday = strtotime("-1 hour next tuesday");
    $until = $nextTuesday - $now;
    if(empty($format)){
        return $until;
    }else{
        return date("$format",$until);
    }
}
```

Just need it to count down, until next tuesday, in a really short way (Not in 20+ lines, like all the other script I've seen)
It should still return a timestamp, if it's possible (Need it for an offline app)

So if anyone could help me, I would be really happy (Not that I'm not happy right now, but I would be even happier) :D

Comment: Javascript has some similar date functions, however, the "-1 hour next tuesday" might not be possible to achieve.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Check out [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

Comment: Getting the difference between today and next tuesday in JavaScript is trivial.  But you are also asking for a date format parsing engine in less than 20 lines of code.  Date formatting is not built in to JavaScript.  You can manually format a date in 1 line of code, but you can't reasonably parse a format string and return a formatted date string in under 20 lines of code.  Use an existing library or write your own Date formatting engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [phpjs](http://phpjs.org/pages/home) site. They have code showing how a substantial number of PHP functions can be done in JS.

Specifically: [`strtotime`](http://phpjs.org/functions/strtotime:554) and [`date`](http://phpjs.org/functions/date:380)

Answer (score 0):

JS doesn't have anything remotely close to strtotime. You'd have to determine  "next tuesday" yourself. Once you've got that, you can extract a timestamp value using .getTime(), which will be the number of milliseconds since Jan 1/1970. This value can also be fed back into a new date object as a parameter, so you can do date math using simple numbers externally, then create a new date object again using the result.

e.g.

```
var now = new Date();
var ts = now.getTime();
var next_week = ts + (86400 * 7 * 1000);
next_week_object = new Date(next_week);
```

Once you've got the "next tuesday" code figured out, the rest is trivial

Answer (score 0):

To get milliseconds till the next tuesday (nearest in the future):

```
function f_until(){
  var now = new Date(Date.now());
  var nextT = new Date(Date.now());
  var cD = nextT.getDay();
  if(cD < 2)nextT.setDate(nextT.getDate() + (2-cD));
  else nextT.setDate(nextT.getDate() + (9-cD));
  nextT.setHours(nextT.getHours() - 1);
  //alert('next tuesday: '+nextT.toString()); 
  return nextT.getTime() - now.getTime();
}
```